# Calculate checksum of file uploaded in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have the below code which uploads file to AWS S3 bucket.

How can i verify if the file has been uploaded successfully or not using checksum?

How to calculate checksum of file in the path and the file uploaded in the S3 bucket are same?

```
public class S3Uploader {

    @Autowired
    private S3TransferManager transferManager;

    public String uploadFile( String bucketName, String key, String filePath) {
        UploadFileRequest uploadFileRequest = UploadFileRequest.builder()
                .putObjectRequest(b -> b.bucket(bucketName).key(key))
                .addTransferListener(LoggingTransferListener.create())
                .source(Paths.get(filePath))
                .build();
        FileUpload fileUpload = transferManager.uploadFile(uploadFileRequest);
        CompletedFileUpload uploadResult = fileUpload.completionFuture().join();
        return uploadResult.response().eTag();
    }
}
```

Comment: See [checking object integrity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/checking-object-integrity.html).

Comment: is aws sdk 2.x.x is compoatble with Java 8?

Answer (score 0):

There may be different ways to go about this but you could for example upload the checksum with the file, maybe to a different /checksums/ path, then wire up your s3 bucket to trigger a lambda to create checksums for uploaded files and compare the results to the uploaded checksums.

Comment: thats not really effecient.i have the checksum for the File from the path.i need to get the checksum once the file is uploaded.

Comment: I mean the whole checksum thing is inefficient. You know that file will either be uploaded properly or will be discarded, right? So, if your purpose is really to make sure file uploaded successfully, then you should wrap your upload code with error checking to see if upload failed. 
When you ask the question how do I do this 'by this', then you already determined a method. If you instead ask how do I do this, then you would get a different answer.